# Place a view below another view at runtime when button is clicked Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, view, runtime

I have a VideoView and a ListView in my RelativeLayout parent view. When the activity is Created by default the VideoView is below the ListView but I desire to change this and place the ListView below the VideoView when a button is clicked at runtime... I have tried this but am getting an error that :"Circular dependencies are not allowed in RelativeLayout"..
Here is the code I have that is throwing an exception

```
class Audio_Player:AppCompatActivity{
ListView audiolist;
VideoView video;
Button change;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 audiolist=(ListView)FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myaudiolist;
video=(VideoView)FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.myvideo);
 change=(Button)FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
 change.Click += layout_change;
   } 
//method to change the layout rule on button click
 private void layout_change(object sender,EventArgs e) {
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WindowManagerLayoutParams.MatchParent, WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent);
LayoutParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below,video.Id);
audiolist.LayoutParameters=layoutParams; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Circular dependencies are not allowed in RelativeLayout

From the shared error, you can not modify the inner existed control of the **RelativeLayout**. That means you only can add View from outside of the Root **RelativeLayout**.

For example , create **another_layout.xml** as follows, and it only contains a Control. You could modify it with your needs control.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/AnotherRootView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:text="AnotherListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/AnotherListView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now back to Root RelativeLayout, and add  `android:id="@+id/RootView"` in its **xml**.

Then we can add `another_layout.xml` in Root RelativeLayout as follows:

```
private void Change_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // get root view
   RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout)FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.RootView);
   // set layout params
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WindowManagerLayoutParams.MatchParent, WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent);
    layoutParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, video.Id);
    // get another layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.another_layout, null,true);

    // get and set data for anther list view
    ListView anotherListView = (ListView)linearLayout.FindViewById(Resource.Id.AnotherListView);
     
    // we can remove the previous list view
    rootView.RemoveView(audiolist);
    // add another list view which inside the anther layout
    rootView.AddView(linearLayout, layoutParams);

}
```